# Radio button function

Tags: tkinter

So I have a code and I want to call it into a function so for example 
if python is selected print something

```
from tkinter import *

r = Tk()
v = IntVar()  


languages=[
    ("Python",1), 
    ("Perl",2),
    ("Java",3),
    ("C++",4),
    ("C",5),
    ("None of above",6)
]

def ShowChoice():
    print ("your choice is",v.get())

Label(r, text="Choose your favourite programming language", justify=LEFT, padx=20).pack()

for txt, val in languages:
    Radiobutton(r, text=txt, padx=20, variable=v, command=ShowChoice, value=val).pack(anchor=W)


mainloop()
```

Comment: what is your question? You've told us what you want but you haven't asked about anything. What part of the problem are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on your current function:

```
def ShowChoice():
    print ("your choice is",v.get())
```

You have to state "if v is pressed, do something". Like this:

```
def ShowChoice():
    if v.get()==1:
        #Do Something
    else:
        print("your choice is", v.get())
```